# Parameter passed as variable and value, both return different answers

Tags: c, function, math, floating-point

My program prints the natural logarithm of a value passed to the function. The odd thing that I observed was when I assigned the value 0.1 to my dummy variable and passed it as an argument my function returns a wrong answer, while if I pass the actual value 0.1 directly, I get the right answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double pow(double val, int x) {
        int i;
        for(i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
                val *= val;
        }
        return val;
}

double log(double val) {
        int i;
        int n = 20;
        double ret_val;
        for(i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                ret_val += pow(-1,i+1) * pow(val-1,i);
        }
        return ret_val;
}

int main() {
    double dummy;
    dummy = 0.1;
    printf("%f",log(dummy));
    printf("%f",log(0.1));
    return 0;
}
```

Am I missing something here? How is it possible for the same value to return different answers?

Comment: `double ret_val;` : You used uninitialized variable.

Comment: Also Avoid using built-in function names (`log` and `pow`).

Answer (score 2):

```
double ret_val;
```

is used **uninitialized** in your function `log()`, invoking *Undefined Behavior*.

But I think the problem lies in the fact that in the second case the Standard Header `math.h` provides the `log()` function and that's the one that gets executed (thus you see the correct result).

The wrong result comes from *your* function, that has the uninitialized value.

Change your function to:

```
double mylog(double val) {
        printf("Executed\n");
        ...
}
```

and you should get:

```
prog.c:3:8: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'pow' [-Wbuiltin-declaration-mismatch]
 double pow(double val, int x) {
        ^~~

Executed
2.117386
-2.302585
```

Now one should think that `math.h` is not included in your code, but some compiler tend to include headers that they think are needed, which is what happened in your case, I think.

A good idea to avoid these nasty situations, is to avoid using built-in function names.

Comment: Yeah you were right! Thanks. I guess my implementation was wrong and the right answer was due to the built-in log function.

Answer (score 1):

Always compile with `-Wall` while learning and address all the warnings that turn up. This would directly avoid the un-initialized return value in `log`.

Your power function will compute not `val^x` as the name would suggest, but `val^(2^(max(0,x)))` as the line

```
val *= val;
```

always computes the square of the recent value of `val`, thus you perform `x` squarings of the input variable.